Tikz matrix with color nodes (traffic light)
I am trying to adjust a command for traffic light (found from some answer for previos question) such that the border of nodes (circles) will be black (line draw = black!100 inside nodes), but it seems that draw = black!100 doesn't change anything.
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, matrix, positioning}

\newcommand\trafficlight[3]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-1.5mm]
        \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
        ampersand replacement = \&,
        rounded corners,
        draw = blue!100,
%       fill = blue!30,
        column sep = 1.5mm,                  
        nodes = {circle, draw = black!100, fill = #1, minimum size = 5mm, inner sep = 0mm,
            anchor = center},
        ]
        {
            |[#1]| \& |[#2]| \& |[#3]| \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\trafficlight{red}{yellow}{green}

\end{document}

I will be grateful for any help!

That's unecessary complicated, with an obscure result, indead. // I suggest using one or more \pic commands, which draws your trafficlight. See https://tikz.dev/tikz-pics#pgf.back/pic for details, and e.g. https://tikz.dev/pgfkeys#pgf./handlers/.code:2:args for passing arguments (it's not the best chapter; try searching this site for examples, instead). // Then you'll have everything inside a \tikz{} environemnt, which you can use in runnung text wherever you want.

|[#1]| sets both draw and fill color. Try:

\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, matrix, positioning}

\newcommand\trafficlight[3]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-1.5mm]
        \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
        ampersand replacement = \&,
        rounded corners,
        draw = blue,
%       fill = blue!30,
        column sep = 1.5mm,
        nodes = {circle, draw = black, fill = #1, minimum size = 5mm, inner sep = 0mm,
            anchor = center},
        ]
        {
            |[fill=#1]| \& |[fill=#2]| \& |[fill=#3]| \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\trafficlight{red}{yellow}{green}

\end{document}

BTW, fontsize is not a valid option (12pt is), and black!100 is the same as black. Also, your macro adds several spaces around...

